# Bootstrap popover doesn't trigger on elements just added to the DOM

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I'm showing an icon when I hover over a div.

And on clicking that icon, I want to show a popover.

For some reason, the popover doesn't trigger at all.

My HTML:

```
<div class="kpi">
    <p>this is the kpi</p>
</div>
```

My JavaScript:

```
$('.kpi').live('mouseenter', function(e) {
        $(this).find('p:first').append('<span class="gear" style="margin-left: 10px; position: absolute;"><i class="icon-cog"></i></span>');
    });

    $('.kpi').live('mouseleave', function(e) {
        $('.gear').remove();
    });

    $('.gear').popover({
        title:"titke",
        content:"click me",
        trigger:"click"
    });

$('.gear').live('click', function(e) {
    alert('clicked the gear');    
});
```

Any noob mistake I might be doing?

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pAXGX/).

Comment: Which jquery version are you using? .live() is deprecated and removed from 1.9 use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead

Comment: It's using 1.7 in the fiddle and doesn't work there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `popover` is initialized on non existing element.

```
$('.kpi').live('mouseenter', function(e) {
    $(this).find('p:first').append('<span class="gear" style="margin-left: 10px; position: absolute;"><i class="icon-cog"></i></span>');

    //Call the popover after creation of gear
    $('.gear').popover({
        title:"titke",
        content:"click me",
        trigger:"click"
    });

});

    $('.kpi').live('mouseleave', function(e) {
        $('.gear').remove();
    });


$('.gear').live('click', function(e) {
    alert('clicked the gear');    
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pAXGX/4/)

You need to call the `$('.gear').popover({...})` after the `.gear` element is created and appended to the dom (after `$(this).find('p:first').append(...)`)

Comment: Bootstrap is included in the fiddle.

Comment: bootstrap.css was included, not bootstrap.js was not

Comment: Sorry missed that, still your `popover()` definition is in wrong place

Answer (score 1):

First, you're JSFiddle is missing the jQuery popover plugin: I assume you want to include [this one](http://daveyijzermans.nl/jquery/popover/demo.html).

But the real problem is this line of code:

```
$(this).find('p:first').append('<span class="gear" ....
```

You're dynamically creating a span with a specific class when hovering the `.kpi` . The initialization of the .popover has already been executed, and doesn't execute again for this class. We'll need to apply it once again for the newly created element like this:

```
var span = $('<span class="gear" style="margin-left: 10px; position: absolute;"><i class="icon-cog"></i></span>');

span.popover({
    title: "title",
    content: "click me",
    trigger: "click"
});

$(this).find('p:first').append(span);
```

Although it might not be fully what you want (since you had a second "`click`" handle applied), I assume you can take it from here.

**[JSFiddle proof](http://jsfiddle.net/pAXGX/3/)**.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. In the meanwhile I found the same things you pointed out.